# Comparing two arrays of objects, and update the value of the second one. Very slow

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, lodash

Below is my working code example, but the problem i'm having is when I have over 100k records this script takes a very long time to run and I was wondering if there was a faster way of doing this.

Note: I have two arrays of objects and I need to set the second array's object names based on the first one's. The IDs will match between the two and the order will be random.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let res1 = [
  {id:1, name:'Sandra'},
  {id:2, name:'Bill'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter'},
  {id:4, name:'Jill'}
];

let res2 = [
  {id:2, name:'John'},
  {id:4, name:'Bobby'}
];

_.forEach(res1, function(data1) {
  _.forEach(res2, function(data2) {
    if (data1.id === data2.id) {
      data2.name = data1.name;
    }
  });
});

// res2 = [{id:2, name:'bill'},{id:4, name:'Jill'}];
```

Comment: A quick and small betterment, if your strategy is to use MxN loop, then better to use for loop, and break whenever you are done with your operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map by id of `res1`, and than iterate the 2nd array, and replace the name of each id you find the `res1map`.

```js
const res1 = [
  {id:1, name:'Sandra'},
  {id:2, name:'Bill'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter'},
  {id:4, name:'Jill'}
];

const res2 = [
  {id:2, name:'John'},
  {id:4, name:'Bobby'}
];

const res1Map = _.keyBy(res1, 'id');

res2.forEach((o) => res1Map[o.id] && (o.name = res1Map[o.id].name));

console.log(res2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: good one! Thumbs up (y), was thinking it will be better to do `o.name = (res1Map[o.id] || o).name` in order to increase performance a bit?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee - nice idea. I'm not sure how much of a performance gain that will be, if it all, but you're welcome to profile it :)

Comment: yeah, in most of the positive case if we have to assign, then it will not fetch the value using the key twice. but if most of the cases are negative then using this we will unnecessary assign the same name again and again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `forEach` and `find`:

```js
let res1 = [
  {id:1, name:'Sandra'},
  {id:2, name:'Bill'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter'},
  {id:4, name:'Jill'}
];

let res2 = [
  {id:2, name:'John'},
  {id:4, name:'Bobby'}
];

res2.forEach((item) => {
  item.name = res1.find((person) => person.id === item.id).name
}); 

console.log(res2);
```